# How to share files between UWP app and Asp.Net Core in Window 10 IoT?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, asp.net5

I have a headless uwp app in my raspberry pi 2 (Window 10 IoT Core) that host a TCP socket server. I want to read and edit some config files of the uwp app via the internet so that I decide to create and host an asp.net core (asp.net 5) app in my raspberry to do that. But I don't know how to make the asp.net app can access to read and edit files of the uwp app.

Note: I can using TCP socket in uwp app to read and edit files via the internet but I think this is not the best way to do.

I will very thankful if someone can show me:

How to make the asp.net core app can access to read and edit files in the uwp app?

Or another way to read and edit files of uwp app via the internet.

Many thanks for your comment and answer.